# No overload matches this call when iterating through node.js process events

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using a library that adds `uncaughtException` and `unhandledRejection` listeners by default.  I wish to remove them.

Here's my code:

```
["unhandledRejection", "uncaughtException"].forEach((eventName) =>
  process
    .listeners(eventName)
    .map((handler) => process.off(eventName, handler))
  );
```

TypeScript gives me this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Signals'.
```

Looking at `global.d.ts` included with `@types/node` I can see that the declarations are made as such:

```
listeners(event: "uncaughtException"): UncaughtExceptionListener[];
listeners(event: "unhandledRejection"): UnhandledRejectionListener[];
listeners(event: Signals): SignalsListener[];
```

So it seems like the TypeScript compiler thinks I wish to use the `event: Signals` function signature.  Which is not what I want!

Is there a way to tell TypeScript which one I want to use?  Or otherwise fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the `UnhandledRejectionListener` you see that it is defined like so:

```
type UnhandledRejectionListener = (reason: {} | null | undefined, promise: Promise<any>) => void;
```

with two parameters - and since the `SignalsListener` is defined like so:

```
type SignalsListener = (signal: Signals) => void;
```

typescript assumes you wanted to use the `SignalsListener` type.

To make it work you have to pass a handler of type `UnhandledRejectionListener`